# How to fill in an array of objects from a file

Tags: java, oop

Here I am trying to fill my array of objects by using the `BufferedReader`
The problem is that I got an error stating that the array is out of index at 1

Also each token in the file is separated by a single space so that i could split token in a string array and divide it on the attributes

The file content

```
Introduction_to_Algorithms Thomas_H.Cormen 2011 2 18
Code_Complete Steve_McConnell 1946 2 18
Design_Patterns Erich_Gamma 2004 2 18
The_Pragmatic_Programmer Andrew_Hunt 2021 2 18
Head_First_Design_Patterns Eric_Freeman 1937 2 18
Refactoring Martin_Fowler 2003 2 18
Clean_Code Robert_C.Martin 2008 2 18
BRIGHT_STAR Yuyi_Morales 1867 2 6
DREAM_STREET Tricia_Elam_Walker 1927 2 5
THE_LONGEST_STORM Dan_Yaccarino 1943 2 5
NICKY_&_VERA Peter_Sís 1781 2 4
UNSPEAKABLE Carole_Boston 1677 2 6
WATERCRESS Andrea_Wang 1884 2 12
WE_ALL_PLAY Julie_Flett 1925 2 15
```

(( Name,Author,Released,numCopies,properAge,science <boolean> ))

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class BooksReader {

    static book arbook[] = new book[14];

    public static void array_filler() throws FileNotFoundException {

        String Line = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MyPath"));

            while ((Line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                int i = 0;

                String ar[] = Line.split(" ");
//The attributes of each object are two strings and 3 integers
               arbook[i] = new book(ar[0], ar[1], Integer.parseInt(ar[2]),Integer.parseInt(ar[3]), Integer.parseInt(ar[4])); //here is the error 
                i++;
               
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BooksReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BooksReader.array_filler();
    }
}
```

```
public class Book {

    private String bookName;
    private String bookAuthor;
    private String SerialNumber;
    private int numCopies;
    private int properAge;
    private int bookReleaseDate;
/// here is the non default constructor of class named book 
    public Book(String bookName, String bookAuthor, int bookReleaseDate, int numCopies, int properAge) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
        this.numCopies = numCopies;
        this.properAge = properAge;
        this.bookReleaseDate = bookReleaseDate;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public int getNumCopies() {
        return numCopies;
    }

    public int getProperage() {
        return properAge;

    }

    public void setBookName(String BookName) {
        this.bookName = BookName;
    }

    public void setBookAuthor(String BookAuthor) {
        this.bookAuthor = BookAuthor;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(int bookReleaseDate) {
        this.bookReleaseDate = bookReleaseDate;
    }

    public void setNumCopies(int numCopies) {

        this.numCopies = numCopies;

    }

    public void setProperAge(int ProperAge) {

        this.properAge = ProperAge;

    }

    public void setSerialNumber(String SerialNumber) {
        this.SerialNumber = SerialNumber;

    }

    public boolean checkAge(int ageOfUser) {
        if (ageOfUser >= properAge) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int addNumCopies() {
        this.numCopies += 1;
        return numCopies;
    }

    public int decNumCopies() {
        this.numCopies -= 1;
        return numCopies;
    }

}
```

So could any one help me with my code ?
or even suggesting another way of doing that?

Comment: *MyPath* - stange name for a file. But what's in it? Please show

Comment: it is the path of the file

Comment: I know. what's in the file?

Comment: i have showed the content

Comment: Sorry missed it. That file has blank lines in it. That's a problem

Comment: No i ve just added them here for calrity

Comment: The file is readable with no problems i think that the problem with the array of objects

Comment: Your re-initalising the counter `i` *inside* the loop for one thing...
Having said that. I think there could be something wrong with your file as your code is otherwise fine

Comment: Hint: learn about java naming conventions, you are violating them all over the places, that makes your code so much harder to read than necessary. Method names go camelCase in java, like `fillArray()`. variable names start lowercase, too. Class names start upper case and so on. In programming every character matters. Train yourself to be diligent!

Comment: And: see [mcve]. Dont "add empty lines for clarity". Give us exactly what you are using. You adding those empty lines **changes** things. And you see: for a [mcve] ... you actually dont need to read data from a file. Put some example strings into an array, and parse that (that is also how you do this yourself: there is no point in FIRST reading your input from a file - just hardcode it in your code ... and THEN, when you are sure the parsing works, THEN fetch your input from a file).

Comment: Also the stacktrace of the exception would be helpful.

Comment: What does the text between the input file and the code mean? It has 6 parameters while your example file *and* your code only 5 items per row.

Comment: I think you really tried to give us a [mre] by reducing your acutal code (thumbs up for that) but you actually made it not reproducible: please add a minimal version of the *book* class and also the piece of code where your error is happening.

Comment: i have included book class

Comment: As your example from above doesn't throw any exceptions when I tried it: where is your exception thrown. Please add the stacktrace as well. I saw that you marked a line with a comment "error happens here" - but did you actually execute that example from your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to fill an array of objects
firstly , I had to pass on the whole array by a for loop setting it's values to a default values (like 0 for integers and empty string for a string) that I will later overwrite from the file

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `int i = 0;` a few lines up to before the while loop, because the way it is working now, you will always try to access `arbook[0]`

Comment: i tried but it gave me the same error

Comment: even if you always try to access `arbook[0]` that shouldn't give an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: The problem simply is that arbook[0] is the only index that is getting filled in the array and i dont know why it is not incrementing to the other indices

Comment: this problem is exactly addressed by @KevinHoltkamp but you wrote before that you get an index out of bounds?

Comment: yes that is the error i got"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"
even after trying his suggestion

Comment: that means it probably happens when trying to acess `ar[1]`, which probably means you have a problem with the file, is there maybe an empty line at the start of the file?